# Reverse Triggered Animation If Method Fails Using Xaml, Not Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard, eventtrigger

I have a login form with a button (**btnLogin**). When a user clicks **btnLogin**, the following `Storyboard` is triggered to disable **btnLogin, txtUsername, pbPassword** ...

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
    <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False" />
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="txtUsername" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False" />
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="pbPassword" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False" />
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
```

... as this `Storyboard` runs, the `Button.Click` event is also attached to a `btnLogin_Click` method which verifies the users credentials. Fair enough!

Currently, if the login attempt fails, I have to use the following (dirty?!) code in `btnLogin_Click` to re-enable the **btnLogin, txtUsername, pbPassword** controls so the details can be re-entered ...

```
btnLogin.Triggers.Clear();
btnLogin.BeginAnimation(UIElement.IsEnabledProperty, null);
txtUsername.BeginAnimation(UIElement.IsEnabledProperty, null);
pbPassword.BeginAnimation(UIElement.IsEnabledProperty, null);
```

Can i handle this re-enabling using Xaml instead? I'm sure I can, I just can't figure out how to do it?!

Thanks for your help :O)

---

**UPDATE**

I've tried using `EnterActions` and `ExitActions` as suggested by bars222, but this approach has no means to determine if the `btnLogin_Click` event resulted in a successful or unsuccessful login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I clearly understand, you want to set `IsEnabled` to true after the login attempt. In that case you can use `EventTrigger.EnterActions` and `EventTrigger.ExitActions` triggers. Here some example.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
    <EventTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False" />
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger.EnterActions>
    <EventTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="True" />
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger.ExitActions>
</EventTrigger>
```

**Update**

Solution with data binding. You can create some property, that indicates authorization process. You should update this during auth process.

```
private bool _isAuth;
public bool IsAuth
{
    get { return _isAuth; }
    set { _isAuth = value; NotifyPropertyChanged( "IsAuth" ); }
}

#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
#endregion
protected void NotifyPropertyChanged( String info )
{
    if ( PropertyChanged != null )
    {
        PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( info ) );
    }
}
```

You should set `DataContext` of these elements. For example, if you created property in authorization window. You can write in constructor.

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

And bind it to your elements to enable/disable it.

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding IsAuth}" />
```

Comment: Also I think it's better to use data binding for you case, but it requiers some code behind.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, that method doesn't disable the button at all. I think it probably disables, then immediately enables it. Can you give me more information regarding the databinding solution you mentioned please?

Comment: For first answer I suggested that authorization form will be disabled after success auth process. Updated answer with data binding example.

Comment: If there is some complex animation for enabling/disabling elements, you should use `DataTrigger` with binding to `IsAuth` property.

Comment: Thanks very much again ... you are right, i do have some extra animations in my storyboard ... I was just looking at `DataTriggers` ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970679%28v=vs.90%29.aspx ... but I wouldn't have gone in that direction without your help :O)